# Firebase auth.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword complaining about email format

Tags: string, email, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

On firebase, using vue.js, when registering and trying to add more info about the user to the database I am running into a really frustrating error when the app tries to write the newUser email to Firebase. The app simply breaks when I the email is part of an object.

I am using the createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password) method to authorise and register a user (on the user list) and then calling a function to register the same user on the database.

this is the error i am getting:

[image]

As you can see the console is outputting a string joaoalvesmarrucho@gmail.com while complaining it's not a string. :/

I have converted the email to a string with no success.

HTML TEMPLATE:

```
<form v-on:submit.prevent>
        <div class="control">
          <input class="input" v-model="newUser.name" type="text" placeholder="Your Display Name">
        </div>
        <div class="control">
          <input class="input"  v-model="newUser.email" id="email" type="email" placeholder="joew@bloggs.com" >
        </div>
        <div class="control">
          <input id="password" v-model="newUser.password" class="input" type="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="control">
          <input id="confirm_password" class="input" type="password"  placeholder="Retype your password" v-on:keyup="checkRetypePassword">
        </div><span id='message'></span>
        <button type="submit" class="button is-primary" v-on:click="signUp">Register</button><span> or </span><button type="submit" class="button is-primary" v-on:click="googleSignUp">Register with Google</button>
      </form>
```

SCRIPT:

```
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      users: usersRef,
      // username: this.$store.getters.getUser.displayName,
      newUser: {
        name: '',
        email: '' , 
        password: '',
        uid: '',
        }
    };
  },
methods: {
    signUp: function() {
      var jsonEmail = JSON.stringify(this.newUser.email); 
      var email = jsonEmail.replace(/\"/g, ""); 
      console.log(email);
      firebaseApp.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password).then(function(user) {
        logUser(user); // callback push user to database
        console.log(email);
      }, function(error) {
        alert(error.message + error.code);
    });
    function logUser(user) { 
      usersRef.push(this.newUser);
      this.name = '';
      this.email = ''; // ERROR: "email" must be a valid string
      this.uid = firebaseApp.auth().currentUser.uid;
    }
```

Could you please give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working simply by getting the value from the email field. Hope this is useful to somebody in the future:

HTML

```
<form v-on:submit.prevent>
        <div class="control">
          <input class="input" v-model="user.name" type="text" placeholder="Your Display Name">
        </div>
        <div class="control">
          <input class="input"  v-model="user.email" id="email" type="email" placeholder="joew@bloggs.com" >
        </div>
        <div class="control">
          <input id="password" v-model="user.password" class="input" type="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="control">
          <input id="confirm_password" class="input" type="password"  placeholder="Retype your password" v-on:keyup="checkRetypePassword">
        </div><span id='message'></span>
        <button type="submit" class="button is-primary" v-on:click="signUp">Register</button><span> or </span><button type="submit" class="button is-primary" v-on:click="googleSignUp">Register with Google</button>
      </form>
```

SCRIPT:

```
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      users: usersRef,
      user: {
          name: '',
          email: '', 
      }, 
      users: [{
          name: 'John Doe',
          email: 'john.doe@gmail.com', 
          uid: "should be actual User UID",
      }], 
    };
  },
methods: {
    signUp: function() {
      firebaseApp.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value).then(function(user) {
                  }, function(error) {
        alert(error.message + error.code);
    });
```